# Jupyter always shows array dtype as float

Tags: numpy, jupyter

I am having a problem with Jupyter in which the magic command ?, as in

```
testImage?
```

tells me that my image arrays are all dtype=float. This is a major problem for troubleshooting since when I have a real type problem, I can't see what's going on with the ?. I've tested it at multiple points in my code and this is a consistent problem. Below is one:

```
im = 0

testImage = cv2.imread(imageList[im])
loadImage = np.copy(testImage)
testImage = cv2.cvtColor(testImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

testImage?
print(testImage.dtype)
```

The query tells me the dtype is float, while the print command output uint8.

Comment: `?` is just a way to look at the docstring, it does not give you information about that particular instance. `dtype` there shows the default value for `ndarray` that's it.

Comment: I see. Is there a magic command for querying an instance?